# How to say 'many times a day'?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

How can I say many times a day? For example, if I wanted to say 'You should drink water many times a day'.

> 毎日(something)回、みずを飲んだほうがいいです。

Would this format be correct? If so, what should I put in the above slot?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> You should drink water **many times** a day'

I would use [何回]{なんかい}も.

> [一日]{いちにち}に**[何回]{なんかい}も**[水]{みず}を[飲]{の}んだ[方]{ほう}がいいです。/ 飲まないといけません。/ 飲んでください。